# Размер столбцов таблицы [closed]

Tags: java, swing

Создаю таблицу, в которой все столбцы одинаковые и их положение можно менять в работающем фрейме. То есть их можно перетаскивать мышкой.

```
public panelRight() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        final JTable tbl = new JTable(100, 5);
        Cursor cursor = new Cursor(1);
        tbl.setCursor(cursor);
        JScrollPane scrlPn = new JScrollPane(tbl);
        add(scrlPn, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
```

Проблема в том, что мне нужно установить вручную размер каждого столбца, и зафиксировать их, чтобы они не перемещались.
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

```
fixedTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
fixedTable.setReorderingAllowed(true);
```

[остальное тут](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html)

Comment: AutoResizeMode мы выключили, но как установить значение для каждого столбца?

Comment: table.setRowHeight(20);

Comment: это высота строки, а не ширина столбца. а нужна его ширина..